# How do you reset a Nexxt 54M Wireless AP Router?

Tags: router

I have this Nexxt router, and I haven't been able to reset it correctly. I pressed the thin button in the back (which you have to press with a pen point or something similar, really slim), but haven't managed to make it work.

The CPU, WLAN and power lights go on and remain still. The lights for the connected cables don't turn on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual...

> I forget Password (Reset the Router without Login
>
> - Reboot the AP.
> - Press and hold the default button wait for a few seconds until the CPU LED indicator stays green.
> - After the above those steps, the manufacture’s parameters will be restored in the Router. The default password is “guest”.

Have you tried pressing and holding the reset button during the boot process? (ie: press it in, power off, and power back on while it's still depressed)

Comment: Apparently the router was stuck or something. I followed this process a couple of times until I finally managed to make it work. Probably some hardware problem, it's working now. Thanks!